# How to run a single test in nightwatch

Tags: functional-testing, nightwatch.js

How do I run only `Test 3` from the following tests?

```
module.exports = {
  'Test 1':function(){},
  'Test 2':function(){}
  'Test 3':function(){}
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

A new parameter **--testcase** has been added to run a specified testcase.

```
nightwatch.js --test tests\demo.js --testcase "Test 1"
```

It's a new feature since the v0.6.0

https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch/releases/tag/v0.6.0

Answer (score 9):

You must use **specific tags before function** and **separate all functions in diferent files** under tests directory, and then call command with *--tag* argument. See [wiki nightwatch tags page](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#test-tags) and watch this example:

```
// --- file1.js ---
module.exports = {
    tags: ['login'],
    'Test 1':function(){
        //TODO test 1
    }
};

// --- file2.js ---
module.exports = {
    tags: ['special', 'createUser'],
    'Test 2':function(){
        //TODO test 2
    },
};

// --- file3.js ---
module.exports = {
    tags: ['logoff', 'special'],
    'Test 3':function(){
        //TODO test 3
    },
}
```

If you run:

```
nightwatch.js --tag login
```

only runs **Test 1**, however if you run:

```
nightwatch.js --tag special
```

**Test 2** and **Test 3** will be executed.

You can specific more than one tag

```
nightwatch.js --tag tag1 --tag tag2
```

Separate each test function is mandatory because Nightwatch handled with *filematcher* each file. [See Github code](https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch/blob/6e49ffdb9afa7644c4ecf9dc6bc84fc5bd2f00df/lib/runner/filematcher.js).

**PD**: If file has syntax errors, is possible that test don't run or test hasn't been found

Comment: This is pretty awesome - I think what would be optimal is if it worked like mocha and grepping. That's what I was hoping for!

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't work for this way. If you like, check [filematcher.js util lib](https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch/blob/6e49ffdb9afa7644c4ecf9dc6bc84fc5bd2f00df/lib/runner/filematcher.js) from github nightwatch repo

Comment: @albertoiNET could you provide a solution where using nightwatch programmatically? Meaning, running a node script that invokes `nightwatch.runner`

Answer (score 8):

The **--testcase** flag can since version 0.6 be used to run a single test from the commandline, e.g.

```
nightwatch.js --test tests\demo.js --testcase "Test 1"
```

This could be done using either [test groups](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#test-groups) or [test tags](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#test-tags). You can also execute a single test with the `--test` flag, e.g.

```
nightwatch.js --test tests\demo.js
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it only works with:

```
npm run test -- tests/01_login.js --testcase "Should login into Dashboard"

npm run <script> -- <test suite path> --testcase "<test case>"
```

my script in package.json:

```
"test": "env-cmd -f ./.env nightwatch --retries 2 --env selenium.chrome",
```

at nightwatch version 1.3.4

You can also use tags:

```
npm run <script> -- <enviroment> <tag>
npm run test -- --env chrome --tag login
```

just add it to your test case:

```
module.exports = {
  '@tags': ['login', 'sanity', 'zero1'],
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do somthing like:

```
node nightwatch.js -e chrome --test tests/login_test --testcase tc_001
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way of doing so, would be to use the following on each test case that you want to omit:

```
'@disabled': true,
```

This can simply be set to false or removed if you wish to test it.