# Nightwatch js - How to run more tests sequencally

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I have written about 70 tests in nightwatch and many of them depend on each other, therefore they will have to be executed in a certain order, order that I will define. Each test is in a different file and it looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  'Test name example': function (browser) {
    browser

    // test

    }
  };
```

I want to know what is the best way to run these tests in an order that I like?
Is there a way to create a "mother-file", where you import/require all the written tests and then execute them in the order of your liking?
From what I searched online, one solution is: "to prefix each test file with a number indicating the order you want them to be run in" from [How can I run Nightwatch tests in a specific order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703989/how-can-i-run-nightwatch-tests-in-a-specific-order), or to use "--testcase"  as shown in [How to run a single test in nightwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308990/how-to-run-a-single-test-in-nightwatch), but I want to know if these are all the posibilities out there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but you can definitely use "require" and then set the order of your test case.

Let's say you have these test cases:

- testcase1.js
- testcase2.js
- testcase3.js
- and so on.

And the inside of **testcase1.js** for example:

```
module.exports = {
  'NameofTheTest' : function (client) {
   //your test here
  }
};
```

Then you can create, as you said, a "mother-file" for example **mastertest.js** and you can write something like this inside it:

```
var testcase1 = require('../../Tests/BC/testcase1.js');
var testcase2 = require('../../Tests/BC/testcase2.js');
var testcase3 = require('../../Tests/BC/testcase3.js');
module.exports = {
  'Test 1' : testcase1.NameofTheTest,
  'Test 2' : testcase2.NameofTheTest,
  'Test 3' : testcase3.NameofTheTest
};
```

You can set the order of the Tests inside of mastertest.js anyway you like.